# MS Graph Explorer - List joined teams - error 404

Tags: angular, typescript, microsoft-graph-api

I've been reading hundreds and hundreds of posts related to several MS graph explorer API issues without being able to solve mine by myself; I hope I don't overlap with another post and that you'll be kind :) !!

I'm trying to perform the following request in my typescript (angular-cli) app :

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/joinedTeams
```

with this code :

```
private findMyTeams() {
  const that = this;
  this.listMyTeams().subscribe(items => {
    that.joinedTeams = items.value; // used in html *ngFor
  });
}

listMyTeams() {
  var client = this.getClient();
  return from(client
    .api('me/joinedTeams')
    .version("beta")
    .get()
  );
}
```

FYI :

- token is good (I managed to compute other queries in the same app for other purposes e.g One drive ...)
- the Auth process went well
- the code is bugfree (I hope) coming from MS official sample with a bit tweaks but the core dev is not mine => https://github.com/microsoftgraph/angular4-connect-sample
- I'm using the following rights :

  **scope: 'User.Read, User.Read.All, User.ReadWrite.All, Files.Read.All, Files.ReadWrite.All, Sites.Read.All, Sites.ReadWrite.All, Group.Read.All, Group.ReadWrite.All'**

and this is what I always get as my http response from Graph API :

[image]

> VM3361 polyfills.js:3372 GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/joinedTeams 404 (Not Found)

[image]

I've also run the query in MS Graph explorer tool directly and got the unfortunate same result as you can see here below :

[image]

Please note that I have already joined teams as you can see hereafter

[image]

And also that I have a member account on Azure AD as the screen below says so :

[image]

Comment: Did you have login your teams before trying this API? If so, I think you can submit the error response in the MS Graph Explore.

Comment: I don't understand your question, can you be more explicit please  ?

Comment: Did you have log in your teams [at here](https://teams.microsoft.com/)?

Comment: Are you running with application permissions or user delegated? There is no /me with application permissions.

Comment: I'm running with user delegated of course :) ! Typically I have another widget that doest me/root/children to list my one drive repositories and their content and it works perfectly already ...

Comment: yes of course I was logged

Comment: Could you please provide the error message? We could not position the problem from the 404 Error Code

Comment: I already did unfortunately .... This is all that I have : GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/joinedTeams 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Please provide the error message in the MS Graph Explore, for example:`{
    "error": {
        "code": "ErrorAccessDenied",
        "message": "Access is denied. Check credentials and try again.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "70901ca1-07db-4513-981b-b687ed6f3b73",
            "date": "2018-10-16T06:37:11"
        }
    }
}`

Comment: Stack from Chrome added :) !

Comment: Did you have tried this in the MS Graph Explore?

Comment: Actually I was running the query on sample account ! I connected and I got the same 404 error... I've just edited my post above, if you can see . Thanks

Comment: According to the show in MS Graph Explore your posted,  I think you may have no joined teams. Could you please check that whether you have joined some team?

Comment: well.... I'm sure I have !! I just edited my post right now , so can you see my demo account as joined teams :) Thanks.

Comment: According to the screenshot you posted, you used a `gmail` account to login the MS Graph Explorer. It's not a valid `Azure AD account`. I guess it may be a guest account in the Azure AD Account. You need to use the `normal user` account to access the API but not the `guest account`. Then the API should works well.

Comment: Indeed, never thought it would be a problem. Thanks I'll check that on my side then. Thanks for your answers and time Kikang.

Comment: I have submit the answer according to the comments, if something is missing, please help me modify the answer and please mark the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your description, I assume you want to list the joined teams but get the 404 Error Code.

Based on my test, There are two reasons why this problem may occur.

#1, when we use the following API, we should [login in our teams](https://teams.microsoft.com/) first.

`GET /beta/me/joinedTeams`

#2, we should use a valid `Azure AD` account to access the API. The guest account in the Azure AD Account may couldn’t access the teams resources.

Comment: Hi Kikang, thanks for your efforts and answers ! the #1 is ok on my side so no worries about that. Regarding #2 do you know how can I ensure myself that my account is Azure AD "valid" ?

Comment: We can [login here](https://aad.portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_AAD_IAM/UsersManagementMenuBlade/AllUsers) and check the user's `userType` is guest or member, and we should also check the `Source`

Comment: I'm a member => screenshot added in the original . What is the Source ?

Comment: The link is not the teams, it is a Azure Ad User manage portal. When we log in this site, we can see the all users with their `user type` and `source`

Comment: Yes, the user's email `admin@mycapagnie401.onmicrosoft.com` is a member of the Azure AD. But you login in with the `jeremy.darchy@gamil.com` on the MS Graph Explorer

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following you. As far as I understand the admin@mycompagnie401.onmicrosoft.com is my Username, the email I defined is for my login only. And I checked my profile I'm really a user type Member... And my account profile holds both informations.

Comment: Hi @kikang,

I finally manage to get what you meant. I recreated another user inside the AD Directory with the appropriate source "Azure Active Directory" and it works like a charm ! Thanks again for your time !

Comment: Could you please modify the answer and mark this as answer to help another?

Comment: Can you share the proper answer? Right now I have the same problem with 404 respond.