# "ResourceNotFound" with 404 for joinedTeams api in graph explorer

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I'm playing around with Teams graph APIs in [graph explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer/preview)

I'm sure I have a team that I've joined.

[image: Teams screenshot]

However, graph explorer continue to return

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "ResourceNotFound",
        "message": "Resource not found.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "bab26952-190e-4670-844c-f9ed3aec9cb2",
            "date": "2020-02-14T16:57:34"
        }
    }
}
```

with 404 status code after I authenticated with my own account.[image: Graph screenshot]
What should I do to fix this?

Graph explorer works well when I'm not logged in but breaks like provided when I do.

There is another [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52795516/ms-graph-explorer-list-joined-teams-error-404) asked on SOF that maybe related, however the explanation is unclear and I'm unable to figure out what they're talking about.

If it is a permission problem, how do I resolve it in graph explorer? Is it achievable?

The permission Tab is as following.
[image: Permission Screenshot]

Comment: Yes it's getting 404 due to permission you can see the modify permissions button in graph explorer, You can consent the permission and try again let me know if you face this issue again...

Comment: Thanks for the reply, sure I've checked the permission tab and the documentation for "List joinedTeams" which states I should give at least "User.Read.All" permission to graph explorer, however, in the permission tab, User.Read.All row, the status is "Consented" The screenshots are attached back to the original question.

Comment: Yes Hilton is correct it's a button when you click it will be italicized

Comment: Did you solve this problem?

Comment: @ajonk nah, I didn't

Answer (score 0):

It's not actually Consented - you need to click the blue "Consent" button (yes, it's a button). When you do so, it will change to just plain text, italicized: *Consented*

Comment: @wusatosi did you see the updates on this question? My answer here and the comment on your original question?

Comment: It looks like it’s impossible to consent with current Edge/Chrome, due to the popup being blocked because of Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB).